# How to customize QTableWidget's checkbox?

Tags: c++, qt, checkbox, qtablewidget, qcheckbox

I've tried to set some style for check box in Qt. I know that `QTableWidget` has `QCheckbox`, but the problem is that I have no idea how to set style for it.

```
QTableWidgetItem *checkBoxItem = new QTableWidgetItem();
checkBoxItem->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
table->setItem(row, column, checkBoxItem);
```

When I use `setStyleSheet()` for `checkBox`:

```
checkBoxItem->setStyleSheet("...");
```

I get an error:

```
'class QTableWidgetItem' has no member named 'setStyleSheet'`
```

I want to do some operations with `checkBox`.

Here is the complete code for the first `QTableWidgetItem`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) 
    m_tableWidget->setRowHeight(i, 3 * em);
    
QTableWidgetItem *item1 = new QTableWidgetItem(tr("Show Message Preview"));

if (CGlobalZone::m_showMsgPreview)
    item1->setCheckState(Qt::Checked); 
else
    item1->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
    
item1->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
m_tableWidget->setItem(0, 0, item1);
```

[image]

Comment: What do you want to do with check boxes?

Comment: I want to check flag and handle some operation @vahancho

Comment: Try `QTableWidget::setCellWidget`.

Comment: Is it change checkbox's style? How to use it? QTableWidget::setCellWidget(0,0)>setStyleSheet(..)?

Comment: Items of `QTableWidget` are not `QWidget`'s, so you can't apply styles directly. You need to use `QTableView` + write your own delegates with customized checkboxes.

Comment: @afn, I think that has nothing to do with the style sheets at all. Try to set `item1->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);`.

Answer (score 2):

You can style the indicators with QAbstractItemView::indicator { ... } (eg QTableView::indicator:checked, QTableView::indicator:unchecked etc).

You can't apply style directly to the QTableItemWidget, but you can put a stylesheet on the QTableWidget itself or a parent of it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you already have a table widget with at least one column and at least one row:

```
QCheckBox *cb = new QCheckBox(tr("Check me"));
cb->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 85, 0);");
tableWidget->setCellWidget(0, 0, cb);
```